# specify mime type for dataUri when using webpacks asset/inline

Tags: webpack, assets, web-audio-api

I'm loading audio files with webpacks `asset/inline`

```
{
  test: /\.(wav)$/i,
  type: 'asset/inline',
}
```

```
import someWAV from './wav/some.wav'
```

working all fine, files get imported as dataUris.
But the dataUri beginning with: `data:audio/wave;base64,`

I need to change the mime-type to `audio/wav` (without the trailing `e`) to make it work with the audio library I use.

Can you do that in the webpack config, rather than doing something ugly like this?

```
someWAV = someWAV.replace('audio/wave', 'audio/wav')
```

I tried just adding the `mimeType` parameter to the rule, but that didn't work at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks @grzegorz-t, content in the generator callback is the raw content though, so you need to do something like this:

```js
{
  test: /\.wav/,
  type: 'asset/inline',
  generator: {
    dataUrl: (content) => {
      return `data:audio/wav;base64,${content.toString('base64')}`
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: That's why I wrote maybe :)
I never needed it and I just reached for the documentation ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution, maybe it will work:

```js
{
  test: /\.wav/,
  type: "asset/inline",
  generator: {
    dataUrl: (content) => {
      content = content.replace('audio/wave', 'audio/wav');
      return content;
    }
  }
};
```